# Placeholders with the same text as the label - good practice?

Tags: usability, forms, gui-design, labels, placeholder

I have a form such as the following, in which the placeholders have the same exact text as their corresponding labels:

[image]

The alternative being leaving each input without any placeholder. I'm **not** discussing labels vs. placeholders. The labels will stay regardless!

It seems to me that these seemingly redundant placeholders are actually useful, to some degree and to some people. It can save the user from looking at the left to remember which input was he filling (likely in lengthy forms)

I don't see any harm in putting them as the visual impact is very little.

Is there established practice on whether redundant placeholders are helpful/harmful?

Comment: I would have the placeholder text show an example (and you could even get creative and integrate some easter eggs/references).

Comment: Why not: `Email  johndoe@example.com` `Name  John` `Surname  Doe`?

Answer (score 36):

Typically I find using the placeholder text as an example of the intended content is best. So, the label *describes* the field, and the placeholder *exemplifies* the type of content.

Here's a good example, from this article: http://www.pardot.com/faqs/forms/placeholders-and-labels/

[image: placeholder text in field]

Comment: Using placeholders content examples is not good practice. http://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey, not in this case. Nielsen explicitly states that essential information and "important hints or instructions" shouldn't be put in placeholders. This is not essential information or important enough to be put somewhere else, so no problem.

Comment: Oops, your image is broken (because they're broken on the other site). That's why you should always upload a *copy* of images to the Stack Exchange image hosting site—you can do it easily from within the posting interface by clicking the "image" button on the toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

No point in repeating the same information twice. Use placeholder text to help users understand how the data is expected to be entered.

For example displaying the phone number format. Another example is when there are multiple lines for address the cues can be placeholders.

Research by N/n found that some users mistake the placeholder as the field already being filled in but my sense is that given their widespread adoption thanks to the small screens it is very likely that this issue may not be as commonly seen as before.

No harm in having some fields with meaningful placeholders and others empty. At least the users will not learn to ignore the redundancy.

Answer (score 3):

I saw an article from the Nielsen Norman Group saying that Placeholders in Form Fields Are Harmful http://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/

However, they seem to have analyzed placeholders that replace labels or provide additional information. That is not the case in your example.

As you say, my personal sense is that these redundant placeholders can look good and be useful. If you wanted to add variety you could prefix "Your" to the text in the placeholders; e.g.:

Email: [Your Email Address]

Name: [Your Name]

Comment: That's the way to go. You could also use examples, like E-mail: ["john@mail.com"] and Name: ["John Smith"]

Comment: I'm a fan of `E-mail: [your@email.com]`, although I prefer the Material Design approach (icon + placeholder and optional floating label): https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html

Answer (score 2):

No, this seems not to be a good practice.

In the article from Nielsen Norman Group, "[Placeholders in Form Fields Are Harmful](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/)", in the list of seven reasons why placeholders should not be used, the last ones explain not only why you need labels, but why is bad to have not empty inputs:

> 5. Fields with stuff in them are less noticeable.
>      Eyetracking studies show that users’ eyes are drawn to empty fields. At the minimum, users will spend more time locating a non-empty field — a nuisance. At the worst, they will overlook the field completely—a potential business-killing disaster.
> 6. Users may mistake a placeholder for data that was automatically filled in.
>      When there is already text in the field, people are less likely to realize that they can type there. Some users assume the placeholder text is a default value and skip the field completely.
>
> **Placeholder Text in Addition to Labels**
>
> Using placeholder text in combination with form labels is a step in
>   the right direction. (...) However, even when
>   using labels, placing important hints or instructions within a form
>   field can still cause the 7 issues mentioned above, albeit with less
>   severity.

On the other hand, I saw that a good solution for the placeholder text is considered by some designers a floating label. The placeholder text is actually the label showing by default, but once an input field is tapped and text is entered the placeholder text fades out and a top aligned label animates in.

In this article, "[Float Label Pattern](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/float-label-pattern/)", Brad Frost has some good pro/con arguments:

> The Float Label Pattern
>
> Float Label Pros
>
> User keeps context–The main advantage of this pattern is that the user
>   keeps the field’s context after they’ve focused and entered a value.
>   This provides for a more accessible, less frustrating experience.
>
> Clean and scannable by default–This pattern allows for a clean inline
>   label experience by default, and only becomes a little more cluttered
>   once the user has filled things out.
>
> Elegent–It needs to be said: this pattern is sexy. You usually can’t
>   say that about forms. It looks good and the animations are a nice
>   subtle touch.
>
> Float Label Cons
>
> Still doesn’t provide room for both label and placeholder–Because the
>   label is occupying the same space as the placeholder, there’s no room
>   for additional hinting.
>
> Small Label–The label becomes small and possibly hard to read, but at
>   the same time it’s not as big a deal. Once the user has interacted
>   with the input, the label becomes a reference rather than an
>   instruction. Potential for code abuse–Based on the few demos I’ve
>   seen, there’s the possibility of wrecking accessibility and semantics.

Answer (score 1):

You could prefix the placeholders with "Enter your ".

That way they

- stand out more as a placeholder as opposed to content
- give a little bit more info of what the user needs to do, e.g the action of entering text
- and also it means you can add this extra prompt without cluttering your label

Answer (score 0):

seems redundant to do so...why not get rid of the placeholders
or if you must then try something like

- **EMAIL:** your best email
- **NAME:**  first,last

this way you can get rid of the surname all together

Comment: I disagree with getting rid of surname. [Names are complicated](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: if you separate it by a comma, then it does not matter...unless your parse isn't set up that way.

Comment: what if someone screws it up and puts last, first instead of first, last? Even if your placeholder is explicit, once you put text in there there's no indication of ordering. This is not a good solution.

Comment: @Seiyria, names being complicated are actually a good reason to ditch the surname field. Unless your app needs to handle names specifically, there's no need to separate a full name into its components.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez In most cases, people collect name so they can use it appropriately, ie, "Hello Seiyria!" when emailing (it sounds a lot more "natural", or displaying your name in a title bar. Generally, a first name is more personable and it adds a nice touch to your application. If you're not doing these things and you're collecting a name, then I have to wonder why.

Comment: @Seiyria I love the irony of your first comment pointing out that names are complicated, and then your follow-up comment making an assumption that everyone prefers to be called by their first name.

Comment: @MaskedMan It was a _very simplified_ example of why you _would_ separate the name. If you're building something like that, there should clearly be settings to indicate what you prefer to be called.